# BASH script to search for files in folders of 4 digits and older than 7 days

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

unset result
result=$(find /home -path "$HOME/TestDir/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/test*" -mtime -7 -print -delete 2>/dev/null)
[ "$result" ] || echo "There are no recovery files older than 7 days"
```

In the `/test` part I actually need to find 2 file names. Those that begin with `E*` and those that begin with `P_*`. can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find $(find -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]") -name "[test]*" -mtime -7 -exec rm -i {} \; || echo "There are no recovery files older than 7 days"
```

The `||` (**or**) operator looks at the result of the command on its left, and runs the command on the right only if the command on the left failed (based on the return code).

If find does not find any matching files, it will return 1, which will cause `||` to run run the `echo` command.

Comment: Is it possible to put and and statement into the `[test]*` part? I am looking to have `[test && P_]*` will that work?

Comment: I am not sure `[test]*` does what you want. My version of `find` reads it as a character class and matches any file starting with `e`, `s` or `t`. But I suspect `find $(find -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]") -name "\[test && P_\]*" -mtime -7 -exec rm -i {} \; || echo "There are no recovery files older than 7 days"` will work after escaping the `[brackets]`

Answer (score 1):

From **man find**

> **EXIT STATUS**
>   **find** exits with status 0 if all files are processed successfully, greater than 0 if errors occur. This is deliberately a very broad  description, but if the return value is non-zero, you should not rely on the correctness of the results of **find**

Thus if there is no matched files the exit status is remain 0. So better to check whether output is empty:

```
unset result
result=$(find ~/TestDir -path "$HOME/TestDir/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/test*" -mtime -7 -print -delete 2>/dev/null)
[ "$result" ] || echo "There are no recovery files older than 7 days"
```

Comment: Thank you @Costas In the `/test` part I actually need to find 2 file names. Those that begin with `E*` and those that begin with `P_*`. can this be done? I have changed the original above to reflect your changes

Comment: @Eekfonky change `-path "…"` to `-regex "$HOME/TestDir/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/\(E\|P_\).*"` or use `-o` option `-path "$HOME/TestDir/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/E*" -o -path "$HOME/TestDir/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/P_*"`

Comment: **NOTE!** To use above with other option (e.g `-mtime -7`) you have to repeat it in both side of `-o`option or put both variats into parenthesis like `\( -path "$HOME/TestDir/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/E*" -o -path "$HOME/TestDir/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/P_*" \)`